# C# is not saving data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

When I replaced my concatenated insert with parameters, `INSERT` stopped saving to database.

I use:

```
Int32 rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                          
var totalRecords = (new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EmpInfo", cmd.Connection)).ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("RowsAffected: " + rowsAffected.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("Total Records: " + totalRecords);
```

but then, the return value is 1 for `RowsAffected`, and -1 for `totalRecords`.

```
if (Status == RegistrationStatus.r_OK)
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.EmpInfo(EmpYear, EmpStatus, LName, FName, JobTitle, EmpPay, EmpDoB, EmpSex, EmpAddr, EmpCity, EmpState, EmpZIP, EmpCountry, EmpEAddr, EmpTelNo, EmpMobileNo, EmpDate) VALUES (@EmpYear, @EmpStatus, @LName, @FName, @JobTitle, @EmpPay, @EmpDoB, @EmpSex, @EmpAddr, @EmpCity, @EmpState, @EmpZIP, @EmpCountry, @EmpEAddr, @EmpTelNo, @EmpMobileNo, getdate())";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RB-DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=TimeDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=bautista7"))
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                ParameterName = "@EmpYear", Value = EmpYear });
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpYear", EmpYear);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpStatus", Value = "Active" });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@LName", Value =   regLname_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@FName", Value =   regFname_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@JobTitle", Value = "NULL" });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpPay", Value =   PayType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString()});
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpDoB", Value =   regDob_dtp.Value.Date  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpSex", Value =   gender });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpAddr", Value =   regAddr_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpCity", Value =   regCity_text.Text  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpState", Value =   regState_text.Text  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpZIP", Value =  regZip_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpCountry", Value = regCountry_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpEAddr", Value = regEmail_text.Text  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpTelNo", Value =   regTel_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpMobileNo", Value =   regMob_text.Text});

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: You should hide your password in the post

Comment: in `Int32 rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` what exactly are you executing here ?

Comment: Use ExecuteScalar()  `(new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EmpInfo", cmd.Connection)).ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: your parameters adding are very long. you can simply do `cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramname, Sqldbtype, characterlimit).Value = Textbox.Text`

Comment: there is not need for a transaction if that is the only statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `ExecuteNonQuery` in the right place and you need to use `ExecuteScalar` in the other place. Also `rowsAffected` will always be 1 since you're inserting just one record.

```
if (Status == RegistrationStatus.r_OK)
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.EmpInfo(EmpYear,EmpStatus,LName,FName,JobTitle,EmpPay,EmpDoB,EmpSex,EmpAddr,EmpCity,EmpState,EmpZIP,EmpCountry,EmpEAddr,EmpTelNo,EmpMobileNo,EmpDate) values(@EmpYear,@EmpStatus,@LName,@FName,@JobTitle,@EmpPay,@EmpDoB,@EmpSex,@EmpAddr,@EmpCity,@EmpState,@EmpZIP,@EmpCountry,@EmpEAddr,@EmpTelNo,@EmpMobileNo,getdate())";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RB-DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=TimeDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=bautista7"))
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpYear", Value = EmpYear });
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpYear", EmpYear);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpStatus", Value = "Active" });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@LName", Value =   regLname_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@FName", Value =   regFname_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@JobTitle", Value = "NULL" });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpPay", Value =   PayType_cb.SelectedItem.ToString()});
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpDoB", Value =   regDob_dtp.Value.Date  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpSex", Value =   gender });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpAddr", Value =   regAddr_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpCity", Value =   regCity_text.Text  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpState", Value =   regState_text.Text  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpZIP", Value =  regZip_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpCountry", Value = regCountry_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpEAddr", Value = regEmail_text.Text  });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpTelNo", Value =   regTel_text.Text });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmpMobileNo", Value =   regMob_text.Text});

                Int32 rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();                        
                var totalRecords = (new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EmpInfo", cmd.Connection)).ExecuteScalar();
                MessageBox.Show("RowsAffected: " + rowsAffected.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Total Records: " + totalRecords);
           }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I added execute scalar, but empinfo is being written on to, but the second query is successful. im adding a code to stop the write if either fails, but, i dont understand why the first query is not successful.

Comment: `ParameterName = "@EmpYear", Value = EmpYear }); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpYear", EmpYear);` doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 1):

[`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) returns number of rows affected, what you need is [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) which executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row

Comment: @Takarii So, what does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could always cut n paste your sql into *its own file* and let [QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb) generate all the parameter code. Your sql syntax will be validated, you won't have to worry about the types of parameters. Your maintenance will be simplified, and if ever your db schema changes, you'll see straight away if your sql is broken.